# rest api authentication errorSQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, api, rest

**this section makes the authentification function**

```
<?php
$authentication = function()
{   try{
$app=\slim\slim:: getInstance();
$user= $app->request-> headers ->get('HTTP_USER'); 
$pass= $app->request-> headers ->get('HTTP_PASS'); 
$pass= sha1($pass);


$connection= getconnection();
$dbh= $connection-> prepare(" SELECT*  FROM keys where user=? AND pass=? ");

$dbh->execute();
$users= $dbh-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


//print_r($users);
$app-> response->headers->set("content-type","application/json");
$app-> response->status(800);
$app-> response->body(Json_encode($users));

if ($authentication === false)
 {
$app->halt(401);
 }
    }
catch(PDOexception $e)
    {
    echo"error". $e-> getmessage();
    }   
};
```

**this section is for calling authentication for different id**

```
$app-> get("/users/:fb_id", $authentication ,function($fb_id) use($app)

{ 
try{
$connection= getconnection();
$dbh= $connection-> prepare("SELECT* FROM users where fb_id= ?");
 $dbh->bindparam(1,$fb_id);
$dbh->execute();
$users= $dbh-> fetchobject();




print_r($users);
//$app-> response->headers->set("content-type","application/json");
//$app-> response->status(200);
//$app-> response->body(Json_encode($users));
    }
catch(PDOexception $e)
    {
    echo"error". $e-> getmessage();
    }   
 });

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is showing this  "Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bindParams()"

code is here

```
$authentication = function()
{   try{
$app=\slim\slim:: getInstance();
$user= $app->request-> headers ->get('HTTP_USER'); 
$pass= $app->request-> headers ->get('HTTP_PASS'); 
$pass= sha1($pass);


$connection= getconnection();
$dbh= $connection-> prepare(" SELECT*  FROM keys where user=:user AND      pass=:pass");
$dbh->bindParams(':user',$user);
$dbh->bindParams(':pass',$pass);

$dbh->execute();
$users= $dbh-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you aren't using the prepared statements in the conventional way.

Put this lines in your code and i think that it'll work fine

```
$connection= getconnection();
$dbh= $connection-> prepare(" SELECT*  FROM keys where user=:user AND pass=:pass");
$dbh->bindParams(':user',$user);
$dbh->bindParams(':pass',$pass);

$dbh->execute();
$users= $dbh-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Your method also works, but you need to send a array as parameter in the `execute()`. More information and alternatives to my code in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).